# How to write to a text file until the application is closed

Tags: c#, save, text-files

I would like to write to a text file, but I have small problem. When use the code below, it writes just once.

```
        StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
        fileWriter.WriteLine(jointHead.Position.X);       
        fileWriter.Close();
```

When I write like this:

```
        Debug.WriteLine(jointHead.Position.X);
```

it writes the X position until I close the application. How can I write to a text file like I write in Debug mode until I close the application. If I take fileWrite.Close() from where it stays, the program doesnt work.

Thank you...

Comment: just change the appropriate line to: StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt",true); to append to the file.

Comment: Is your goal to append the text unless the application ends and write it on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true);
        fileWriter.WriteLine(jointHead.Position.X);       
        fileWriter.Close();
```

This will allow text written to be appended to the end of the file.
At the moment your writing from the beginning each time.

**edit**

If you wish to clear the file at the start of the application then just perform  the following:

```
StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
            fileWriter.Write("");  
            fileWriter.Close();
```

Comment: thank you, this worked, but it doesnt over write. Is there any way to overwrite everytime I start the application.?

Comment: Added how to clear the file - essentially overwrite the file with a null character and save it.

Comment: I didnt understand. Will I use both at the same time ? I mean, EDIT verison will be at the begining of the application which I dont save anything. First part of the code will be at the place where I want to save ?

Answer (score 2):

From your description I am assuming that the code snippets you give are in a loop.

It's likely that you will get better performance by moving the file open/close outside of the loop (which will also cure your problem).

I you really want to keep opening/closing the file every time, then specify the append flag.

```
using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true))
{
    fileWriter.WriteLine(jointHead.Position.X);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather suggest you to use some sort of logger with a stringbuilder.

```
public class Logger {
    private StringBuilder sb;
    public Logger() { 
        sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    }
    public Log(String log) {
        sb.Append(log).AppendLine();
    } 
    public void Flush() {
        File.WriteAllText(String.Format(@"D:\Logs\Log at {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}.txt", DateTime.Now), sb.ToString());
        sb.Clear();
    }
}
```

This class is much more elegant and reusable solution. It is really acceptable if your target log is not very big.

Answer (score 0):

that constructor of the streamwriter will delete test.txt if it already existed. so every time that bit of code gets executed it will delete the file text.txt that it created earlier. instead, use the [overload for the constructor of streamwriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) that takes an additional bool to append to the existing test.txt file instead of replacing it:

```
StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true);
```

alternatively, you could go with the [File.AppendAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691.aspx) method to append your text to the file. then you don't need to worry about closing the file handle and the method name itself clearly states what's going to happen. to me this would be more convenient and not as obscure as the overloaded streamwriter constructor.

or alternatively, you could go for a logging framework like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). in that case NLog will take care of all your file operations so you're free of worries there then. also, you could configure NLog to write to whatever you like, like your file or, as you mentioned, the debug output window, or the event log, etc etc. also, you can bet on any file operations probably being a whole lot more efficient than your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the stream writer open. But call `Flush` after the `WriteLine` call.

Alternatively you can open the file for appending, instead of recreating it for each line.

---

You might also want to look into an existing logging framework. There are many existing ones, no need to reinvent the wheel. Personally I'd use `Common.Logging` with a backend of your choice.